# Usage of “a” with debido

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

The sentence I was trying to translate is:

> We had to cut short our vacation due to the storm.

A Spanish learning site gave the translation as:

- Tuvimos que acortar las vacaciones debido a la tormenta.

The “**a**” in this sentence really got me confused. Is it really appropriate? I was taught that it’s used only if the object is a person (e.g., **Voy a ver a mi abuela**). Here, that is not the case as the storm is neither a person nor a personified noun. Would it be less appropriate or incorrect to say, “**…debido la tormenta**.”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is appropiate.
This "a" would translate the english "to".
**Due to = debido a** .What follows "a" is the reason always.
Example: "Debido **a** un corte de luz" -> Due **to** an electricity outage.
"an electricity outage" is the reason for the cut.
Try always to transform this kind of sentences into:
"An electricity outage **was the reason for** ..."

Comment: On the second part of the question, it would be incorrect to say "debido la tormenta".

Comment: Nuestro poder de compra se ha visto reducido debido a la inflación